# How to Generate Result from Script Files to Oracle Spool File

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle11gr2

I have a script file containing a mix of DDL and DML which rebuilds a database I use for testing against.  The script file is generating some errors which I need to track down so I attempted to output the results of the script to a spool file using SQLPlus, see below:

```
spool "c:\DBDeploy\ALERTSTLOCAL_Version4x_Rebuild.spl";
@"c:\DBDeploy\ALERTSTLOCAL_Version4x_Rebuild.sql";
spool off;
```

Unfortunately although the spool file gets generated none of the results from the script file (apart from the 'spool off' statement ), get written to the spool file.  Can anyone suggest what is happening here.  I am sure I have used this technique in bygone years, its most perplexing :-/

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: What is in the .sql file you'e running? Does it have its own `set` commands, for instance? Showing that (with real queries replaced with a dummy if you prefer) might show something useful, as might showing any other settings you make before starting the spool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need some tweaking

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF

DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

spool "c:\DBDeploy\ALERTSTLOCAL_Version4x_Rebuild.spl";
@"c:\DBDeploy\ALERTSTLOCAL_Version4x_Rebuild.sql";
spool off;

SET TERMOUT ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET VERIFY ON
```

Tested Screenshot:

[image]

On Windows

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately no joy.  SQLPlus doesn't recognise statement DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

When I comment out the dbms_output line the script runs, but still no output to the specified spool file other than 'spool off;'

Comment: I am not sure what you have tried so far but, for me it is working

Comment: Hmmm... I ran the commands direct from the SQLPlus command prompt.  It looks like you may have run them from within a script.  Will try that and see what happens.

Comment: mine is also sqlplus.

Comment: I'm running against a Windows client and a Windows implementation of Oracle 11gR2.

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);` is a procedure call, so you at least need an `exec` in front of it. I'm not sure it's adding much anyway here though. And your screenshots don't seem to be related to the code you showed, which is confusing; and they don't show spool output (though I don't see why that wouldn't work).

Comment: Ok, not sure what I've done but its all now working.  In the end I executed the spool command manually from the sqlplus cmd prompt, than called the script file.  Consider this now answered.  Thanks for you input guys :-)